# Replace DRL and RF with Java

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule

I tried using `Drools`. I used the `RF` with in their various `DRL`, now I want to try to create something in `Java` that does the same. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code here.

Comment: I want only to know if you know libraries or jars with this function

Comment: What do you mean by `RF`? What was your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a core java library called [Rulette](https://github.com/kislayverma/Rulette) as a sinple drools alternative. You can check if it solves your use cases.